# php resultset to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, resultset

I know it has been asked many times earlier but trust me, I did research for my exact requirements and couldn't find the correct method.

I need the simple array from php resultset from mysql.

here is my code

```
$sql_qry_group = "SELECT country_code, Count(users) as userscnt FROM `users` GROUP by country_code ";
$qry_users_group = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql_qry_group); 
    while($users_country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_users_group)) {
      $countries[] = $nodes_country_set;
     }
```

when I do print_r for $countries[], I get output like below.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [country_code] => US
            [userscnt] => 727
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country_code] => UY
            [userscnt] => 53
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [country_code] => VC
            [userscnt] => 4
        )
```

What I need is to be an array like this

```
$countries = array(
            "US" => 727,
            "UY" => 53,
            "VC" => 4,
}
```

How do I fix it?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `array_column($countries, "userscnt", "country_code");`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your while loop

```
$countries[$nodes_country_set['country_code']] = $nodes_country_set['userscnt'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also You can modify your array like this:

```
$result = [];    
    array_walk($data,function($v,$k)use (&$result){
        $result[$v['country_code']] =  $v['userscnt'];
    });    
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [US] => 727
    [UY] => 53
    [VC] => 4
)
```